# Basic clarification in python, Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

How to print the value of 'a' and 'b' in the     output instead of variable using formatting?

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b
OUTPUT  = Sum of 1 and 2  = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this solve your problem, please run the below:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b

print("The sum of", a,"and", b,"=",c)
```

Output:

```
The sum of 1 and 2 = 3
```

Comment: I need the output as, The sum of 1 and 2 = 3

Comment: print("The sum of", a,"and", b," =",c) then try this. Please mark my answer as correct. I reedited it to suit ur comment here

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b
print("Sum of",a,"and",b,"=",c)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python >3.6 you could use f-strings instead. They are much more readable:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = a+b
print(f"The sum of {a} and {b} = {c}")
```

The Output would be:

```
The sum of 1 and 2 = 3
```